# Microservice deloyed on kubernetes but not giving the desired result

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, microservices

I have successfully deployed a microservice[spring app] on google kubernetes cloud engine.But the endpoint is not working.

Dockerfile
[image]

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: user-management-deployment
 labels:
  app: happy-paws  
spec:
 replicas: 3
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   name: user-management-deployment
   app: happy-paws
 template:
  metadata:
   name: user-management-deployment
   labels:
    name: user-management-deployment
    app: happy-paws
  spec:
   containers:
    - name: user-management
      image: docker/user-management
      ports:
       - containerPort: 9106
```

Service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-management
  labels:
   name: user-management-service
   app: happy-paws
spec:
 type: LoadBalancer
 ports:
  - port: 9106
    targetPort: 9106
 selector:
  name: user-management-pod
  app: happy-paws
```

application.properties
[image]
please help me in understanding the problem.

UPDATE:

After updating the port, the application started working

Services that are up:
user-order-detail LoadBalancer
kubernetes ClusterIP
order-management LoadBalancer
user-management LoadBalancer

user-order-detail hits an endpoint to retrieve all users. I am getting this error :No matches for the virtual host name :user-management**

```
String url = "user-management/user";
        InstanceInfo instance = eurekaClient.getNextServerFromEureka("user-management", false);
        Object response = restTemplate.getForObject(instance.getHomePageUrl() + url +"/" + userId, Object.class);
```

Comment: what tcp port is your service forwarding to ?

Comment: in your service change target port in loadbalancer to 9106

Comment: Node port -31659 Target port -80

Comment: @NimitJohri and what about the value of port ?

Comment: @NimitJohri changing the port to 9106 didn't work

Comment: first check which port your springboot application is running? Have you configured any specific port in application.properties? If not it will run on 8080. You need to expose that port

Comment: @pvpkiran I have exposed the port 9106

Comment: So if u run your application locally(without container) it runs on 9106? then y r u using port 80 in your service yaml.

Comment: @pvpkiran  yes, locally it runs on 9106.  Should I change all the ports mentioned to 80 ?

Comment: change your service yaml to have port number same as the port where your application is running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to understand what service means in kubernetes terminology. On a high level this can be explained as a way to expose your application which is running inside a container (which is running inside a pod(which is running inside a network)) to the external world.

Each of these blocks can have individual network of their own. Hence concept of Service was introduced. This way you can expose what port of the container needs to be exposed to the world and how it needs to be exposed(Service type, which in your case is LoadBalancer).

So if you need to access the application running on port 9106 inside the container you need to expose that port.

```
spec:
 type: LoadBalancer
 ports:
  - port: 9106
    targetPort: 9106
```

Comment: I am trying to call a rest service from inside.it isn't working .any idea why I am unable to perform inter service communication

Comment: what do u mean inside?

Comment: There is another service which accesses the user management service through a rest endpoint. I have deployed it on kubernetes, but is unable to access the rest endpoint

Comment: No matches for the virtual host name :user-management I get this error

Comment: i guess this is coming becos of eureka. You need to check that

Comment: you need to check where erueka is running in kubernetes environment and whether your services are registered to it correctly or not

Comment: services are registered properly.I have updated the details of rest endpoint in the question above. Please let me know if you can help :)

Answer (score 1):

try changing all ports to 9106